# sql request fail with implicit conversion even when no records match clause in prepared statement

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement

I like very much StackOverFlow cause i often found solutions to my problems. But today i'm lost and need your help. I apologize for my poor english.

I have a spring batch software which interrogate a sql server database. For that, we use a prepared statement :

```
select linkcode, cmpcode, doccode, docnum, doclinenum, usrref1 from oas_linkline  where linkcode in ( ? , ? ) and usrref1 is not null and usrref1 <> 0
```

In fact usrref1 is a varchar so there is an implicit cast made. In our case, each records matching the clause < linkcode in (?, ?) > should have a usrref1 with a numeric value, so it should not be a problem.

But there is one case problematic. When no records match < linkcode in (?, ?) >.  The DBMS return the following error :

> nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '00000U20IGRI' to
>   data type int.

The value '00000U20IGRI' concerns records from other linkcodes...

If i use the request directly with Squirrel with arbitrary linkcode values (say A and B) :

```
select linkcode, cmpcode, doccode, docnum, doclinenum, usrref1 from oas_linkline  where linkcode in ( 'A' , 'B' ) and usrref1 is not null and usrref1 <> 0
```

No Problem, the DBMS returns nothing but don't return a error.

If i use the same request in org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader in my code, the same, no problem.

If i parametrize the request with ? and use a org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter to set values, BAM! Big error. It happens as if the clause < linkcode in (?, ?) > was erased form the request.

Does anybody has information for this particular problem? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful when relying on implicit casting in your `where` clause or `join` conditions. If you use an `implicit` cast, it needs to be valid for all records in your tables, otherwise your query can fail depending on the chosen execution plan. I have had cases where queries had been working for years, but suddenly started failing, because the optimiser had picked a different execution plan. As a result it started scanning through different records (even though these records did not match any of the `join` or `where` conditions)  and the implicit cast failed. You can resolved this issue by using explicit casts.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> test_expression [ NOT ] IN 
>       ( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]
>       )
>
> test_expression: Is any valid expression. 
> subquery: Is a subquery that
>   has a result set of one column. This column must have the same data
>   type as test_expression.
>  expression[ ,... n ]: Is a list of expressions
>   to test for a match. All expressions must be of the same type as
>   test_expression.

which is the type of linkcode? because seems to be an INT.
'A' and 'B' can be casted to INT type, but '00000U20IGRI' no.
And this lead you to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thx jaco and Luca for your answers. I effectively think it is possible sql server use another execution plan when using prepared statement forcing a scan of all rows hence causing the error. There appears the need to use a numericity test in the request like this `and ISNUMERIC(usrref1) = 1`.